# How to show image file when i select it in file browser , Carrierwave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave gem for image uploading. i want to achieve image upload and show after uploading completed.

i read the wiki of this gem and used the same code but not working.

```
= form_for @user, html: { :multipart => true, class: 'battle_form' } do |f| 
 = image_tag(@user.file_attachment1_url) if @user.file_attachment1? 
 = f.file_field :file_attachment1, class:'fileInput', name:'image1'
 = f.hidden_field :file_attachment1_cache
```

[Carrierwave Gem GITHUB](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show image after upload, just use `img` tag and you upload file url like:

```
= image_tag(@image_url)
```

This will work after upload completed and refresh current page.

If you just want to preview this image before form submit, you may find some way with `javascript` to solve it, like [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) may help you

Comment: exactly i want to preview image before submit. let me visit given link